# in my code EOFError: EOF when reading a line

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Solution.py", line 11, in <module>
    line = input()
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

```
def afff(line):
    if('2' in line):
        return True
    return False

nam = input()
n = nam.split()[0]
m = nam.split()[1]
count = 0
for i in range(int(m)):
    line = input()
    if afff(line):
        count+=1

print(count)
```

A task:

Student Arman does his homework on databases. He needs to create a database of University students and be able to answer the request - how many students passed the session without a twos. While Arman is doing his task in SQL, you need to write a program that, according to the list of students, disciplines and grades, will give the answer - how many students coped with the session.

Input Format

The first line contains two integers: N - the number of students and M - the number of disciplines. Next, N lines with M numbers in each line are entered - the grade that the student received in each of the M disciplines.

Constraints

(1 <= N, M <= 1000) Grades of students can be in the range from 2 to 5.

Output Format

Print one integer - the number of students who passed the session without deuces.

Sample Input 0

```
3 4
5 3 4 4
5 5 5 4
3 4 2 3
```

Sample Output 0

2

Comment: @Tom Kazres 
I'll take it out of the terminal

Comment: @Tom Kazres I participate in the Olympiad and there is my compiler in the browser

Comment: It sounds like your browser interface isn't allowing multi-line input.  Try running a simpler program to test it:  Just do `a = input()`, `b = input()`, and `c = input()` (three lines of code), followed by `print(a, b, c)` and see if it works.

Comment: @Tom Kazres yes it works

Comment: Ok, from the description, you need to read N lines with M numbers in each.  Instead, you're trying to read M lines.  Change `range(int(m))` to `range(int(n))`.

Comment: @Tom Kazres Thanks bro, this is such a dumb mistake

Comment: @GanzYe Does it work when you tried that?

Answer (score 1):

> Ok, from the description, you need to read N lines with M numbers in each. Instead, you're trying to read M lines. Change range(int(m)) to range(int(n)) -  Tom Karzes

Change `range(int(m))` to `range(int(n))`

The whole code:

```
def afff(line):
    if('2' in line):
        return True
    return False

nam = input()
n = nam.split()[0]
m = nam.split()[1]
count = 0
for i in range(int(n)):
    line = input()
    if afff(line):
        count+=1

print(count)
```